# ReacJS with Baobab, how to release cursor after the component is unmounted

Tags: javascript, user-interface, reactjs, baobab

```
I am new to ReactJS and baobab. Here is what I have:
```

CODE START:

```
var stateTree = new Baobab({
  outputs: {
    campaignList: [],
    exportFields: [],
    exports: [],
    hygiene: [],
    exportFormatList: []
  }
});

var CampaignEdit = React.createClass({
  mixins: [
    stateTree.mixin,
    React.addons.LinkedStateMixin,
    SelectDropdownMixin,
    Router.State
  ],
  cursors: {
    campaignList: ['outputs','campaignList'],
    exports: ['outputs', 'exports']
  },

  componentDidMount: function() {
    this.cursors.campaignList.on('update', this.updateCampaignState);
    this.cursors.accountList.on('update', this.updateAccountState);
  },

  updateAccountState: function() {
    var accountList = deref_cursor(this.cursors.accountList, []);
    var select_options = this.state.select_options;
    for (var i=0; i<accountList.length; i++) {
      var account = accountList[i];
      select_options['owner_id'][account.id] = account.firstname + ' ' + account.lastname;
    }
    this.setState({ 'select_options': select_options});
  },

  render: function() {
    /* render the component here */
  }

});
```

:CODE END

However as the user switched to another component and comes back to this component I get this error: "Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: replaceState(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting component."

```
This is coming up as my current component being loaded is in "UNMOUNTED" state.

My questions is that if the component is already unmounted, why is the unmounted component being reused? Is there a way to avoid this?
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue, caused due to the events bound with cursors. Added componentWillUnmount and unbound the update event.